# How do I send HTTP requests including cookie with ESP8266?

Tags: http, arduino, esp8266

I want to enter to a specific web page  (http address) with user and password that I believe saved in my computer as a cookie.

How can I do it with ESP8266 (Arduino core)?

(For example: I want to get information from my YouTube channel but I need the cookie to sign in.)

Thanks,
 Lani.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: https://github.com/witnessmenow/arduino-youtube-api

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it, adapt to Your needs:

I have used only these 2 libs:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
```

And a snippet:

```
WiFiClientSecure client;
if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return false;
}
client.print(String("GET ") + url + "/lastCompletedBuild/api/json?tree=result HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "User-Agent: BuildFailureDetectorESP8266\r\n" +
               "Authorization: " + token + "\r\n" +
               "Cookie:" + COOKIE_NAME + "=" + cookieValue + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```